# material design for windows phone 8.1 rt

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, material-design

Is material design available for windows phones like android and Ios. 
Anyone share the details about material design for windows phone 8.1 Rt.

Comment: Anyone help me!

Comment: This is a very bad idea. Any app written for a non-native design language will stand out like a sore thumb. Not to mention how awful the material design language and metro both are.

Answer (score 0):

Is not possible. Metro and material design are different concepts and philosophies. 
  Please read this [topic](https://www.reddit.com/r/windowsphone/comments/3c90uw/i_have_to_ask_this_can_microsoft_do_better_than/) - discussion about Metro and Material Design.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [repository](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit). It contains code for UWP apps, modify it to suit Windows Phone 8.1 controls.